# How can I monitor URLs being requested by components in web apps running in Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, monitoring

I'm using a particular web app which for some strange reason runs only in IE and not in Firefox. I need to see which URLs are being fetched by internal components in the web app, such as AJAX requests and video sources being loaded in a video player.

In Firefox I would have used Firebug... is there any tool I can use to see (not necessarily in real time or with a nice GUI) which URLs were requested by IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fiddler - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

It describes its self as a "Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet".

And I've used if for just such a purpose.